# AngularJS ng-if взаимодействие с Twig

Tags: angularjs, twig

Доброго времени суток! 
Встала необходимость использовать AngularJS в Twig'e. Говоря проще, Twig возвращает строку текста через {{info.txt}}. Как можно проверить её содержимое Angular директивой ng-if -> если она не пуста, вывести содержимое.

```
<p class="text" ng-if="{{info.txt}}">{{info.txt}}</p>
```

Буду благодарен любым идеям.

Comment: Делайте это средствами twiga.

Comment: С чего такой взгляд? У меня уже были мысли полностью перейти на AngularJS)

Comment: Вы путаете серверную и фронтенд технологии.

Comment: Или же творите что-то дикое. Если шаблоны - то на ангуларп

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать Twig